# Where does g++ look for libraries to link?

Tags: linux, g++, glfw

So I'm currently using Lubuntu 18.4 32bit and was trying to get the GLFW library up and going. I noticed that when you compile a program using GLFW you need to link many libraries and was wondering where exactly does g++ look in the filesystem when you type `g++ main.cpp -lglfw`?

Comment: Please provide some [mre] (e.g. C++ code with a `main`, and the exact compilation command) in your next question. Consider looking inside [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), reading some C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and using tools like the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Comment: Could you please post the exact and full error log the compiler produces? Please post as text (not an image / screenshot!).

Answer (score 3):

### For compiler:

```
echo | g++ -x c++ -E -Wp,-v - >/dev/null
```

- `echo |` prints empty "source code" and closes stdin
- `-x c++` to specify the language (with this option it prints more detailed info)
- `-E` says `g++` to stop after preprocessing stage
- `-` at the end means read code from stdin
- `-Wp,-v` to pass `-v` directly to preprocessor
- `>/dev/null` to redirect extra output to `/dev/null` (void)

Example output:

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

### For linker:

```
ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
```

- `--verbose` tells `ld` to print settings info
- `| grep SEARCH_DIR` select lib directory info
- `| tr -s ' ;' \\012` makes output pretty (replace  `;` with new line)

Example output:

```
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib")
```

So the GLFW library should be in one of those directories.

---

Source: https://transang.me/library-path-in-gcc/

Comment: OP was asking about library linker search paths, not preprocessor include search paths.

Comment: @datenwolf I added same for linker

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i still have a question: i found a few references to glfw in those directories, but i typed -lglfw and didn't find any specific file/folder with that name.

Comment: @VinnyHorgan try compiling with `-I/usr/include`, with directory which contains GLFW instead of /usr/include